# Why when I switch to a different user environment variable is lost?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

1st container sets the PATH for the user docker

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
USER root
RUN groupadd -r docker && useradd -r -g docker docker
USER docker
ENV PATH /hello-world:$PATH
```

2nd container

```
FROM step_1
USER root
RUN echo $PATH
```

When I go into the second container and switch to user docker PATH variable is reset. If in the second container, I do not switch to the root user, variable stay saved.
Why is this happening? How do I for all users docker save variable PATH?

Commands log:

```
docker build -t step_1 step_1/
docker build -t step_2 step_2/
docker run -it step_2 bash
root@0784c73a84e2:/# echo $PATH
/hello-world:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
su docker
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the `$PATH` variable for multiple accounts. Why do you want to use multiple system users in a Docker container? I'm not sure what you try to achieve but I think this would be against the concept of single purpose containers.

If you only intent to execute some of the commands as a privileged user during the build process you don't have to switch users nor use sudo. Every command from a Dockerfile is executed as root unless specified otherwise.

Comment: I'm need to use multiple users because it is requirements of Phusion Passenger, he does not run as root user. And that's why I need to tell passenger where i store my ruby gems.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
USER root
```

Doesn't doesn't do anything, you're already root inside the container.

[Per the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env), `ENV` variables set do persist between images:

> The environment variables set using ENV will persist when a container is run from the resulting image. You can view the values using docker inspect...

Ignoring all the above, I can't replicate this issue, it works fine for me. Can you paste your full Dockerfiles and the commands you're running to build etc...?

Comment: I can reproduce this now, but I think it's to do with `su docker` line. I don't believe the `USER` instruction uses `su` under the hood, so it's possible that the `su` is screwing with the environment variables.